# FTP permissions on Wordpress Bitnami AWS install?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, bitnami

I have setup a Wordpress site using Bitnami WordPress 4.8.1-0 on AWS (EC2).

I am now migrating a site from Bluehost to the AWS EC2 instance.

I am able to connect to the site via FTP and SSH. I uploaded my plugins and themes with my FTP client, no issues. The site is running with the theme and plugins from the old site. Great.

Now I am trying to upload the media files from `/wp-content/uploads/2017/10`on the old server but apparently I don't have permission to.

If I do a get-info on the plugins or themes folder, I see it's `bitnami:daemon`

[image]

but Uploads and all its subfolders are `daemon:daemon`, although it does look like I have write access:

[image]

I assume for security, but how can I upload all the media files? I'd hate to have to re-add them all via the admin UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try accessing via SSH and modify temporarily the permissions:

```
sudo chown bitnami:daemon -R /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads
```

Then we advise you to restore the permissions.